# How to copy and paste inxml files

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have a XML file where I want to copy a text node value (eg: CIAV819) from  element with attribute=ruleId and paste it to next node  element with attribute=ruleExpression.
Below is the XML file that I want to modify:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Main>
        <installObj uniqueObjects="2822">
            <object class="Installer">
                <visualChildren>
                    <object class="InstallSet">
                        <installchildrenMain>
                            <object class="InstallBundle1">
                                <property name="ruleExpression">
                                    <string><![CDATA[]]></string>  ---paste1
                                </property>
                                <property name="bundleName">
                                    <string><![CDATA[Australia]]></string>
                                </property>
                                <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                                    <object class="CompareVariable">
                                        <property name="ruleId">
                                           <string><![CDATA[CIAV819]]></string> --copy1
                                        </property>
                                        <property name="operandOne">
                                           <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>
                                        </property>
                                    </object>
                                </rules>
                                <installChildren>
                                    <object class="InstallComponent1">
                                        <property name="ruleExpression">
                                            <string><![CDATA[]]></string>  --paste2
                                        </property>    
                                        <property name="componentName">
                                            <string><![CDATA[AUST]]></string>
                                        </property>
                                        <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                                            <object class="CompareVariable">
                                                <property name="ruleId">
                                                    <string><![CDATA[CIAV962]]></string> --copy2.1
                                                </property>
                                                <property name="operandOne">
                                             <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>
                                       </property>
                                             </object>
                                             <object class="CompareVariable">
                             <property name="ruleId">
                                <string><![CDATA[CIAV503]]></string> --copy2.2
              </property>
                                             </object>
                                            </rules>
                                        <installChildren>
                                            <object class="InstallDirCont">
                                                <property name="ruleExpression">
                                                    <string><![CDATA[]]></string>  --paste3
                                                </property>
                                                <property name="operandOne">
                                             <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>
                                     </property>
                                                <rules logicalOperation="OR">
                                                    <object class="CompareVariable1">
                                                        <property name="ruleId">
                                                            <string><![CDATA[CIAV100]]></string> --COPY3.1 </property>
                                                        <property name="operandOne">
                                                    <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>  </property>

                                                    </object>
                                                    <object class="CompareVariable2">
                                                        <property name="ruleId">
                                                            <string><![CDATA[CIAV200]]></string><!-- COPY3.2 -->
                                                        </property>
                                                        <property name="operandOne">
                                                   <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>
                                            </property>

                                                    </object>
                                                </rules>
                                            </object>
                                        </installChildren>
                                    </object><!-- end of installComponent1 -->
                                    <object class="InstallComponent2" >
                                        <!--
                                        Same as above (Install Component1)
                                        -->
                                    </object><!-- end of installComponent2 -->
                                </installChildren>   
                            </object><!-- end of installBundle1 -->
                            <object class="InstallBundle2" >
                                <!--
                                Same structure as InstallBundle1
                                -->
                            </object><!-- end of installBundle2 -->
                        </installchildrenMain>
                    </object><!-- end of InstallSet -->
                </visualChildren><!-- end of visualChildren -->
            </object><!-- end of Installer -->
        </installObj>
        <restorationObjects count="0"/>
    </Main>
```

Copy ‘CIAV819’ value from copy1 location to paste1 location and similarly for other copy2 and copy3 locations.
Wherein for example paste1 location should look like this:

```
<property name="ruleExpression">
   <string><![CDATA[CIAV819]]></string>  ---paste1
</property>
```

paste2 location should look like:

```
<property name="ruleExpression">
   <string><![CDATA[CIAV962 && CIAV503]]></string>  ---paste2
</property>
```

paste3 location should look like:

```
<property name="ruleExpression">
   <string><![CDATA[CIAV100 || CIAV200]]></string>  ---paste3
</property>
```

Only then when I open this xml file in InstallAnywhere  I can see the values populated for Rule Expression field!
I am using the below XSLT transformation to get my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="string" />
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//object[starts-with(@class, 'InstallBundle')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../rules/object/property/string" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//installChildren/object[starts-with(@class, 'InstallComponent')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <string>
           <xsl:for-each select="../rules[@logicalOperation='AND']/object">
                <xsl:value-of select="./rules/object/property/string" />
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt; count(../object)"><xsl:value-of select="' && '" /></xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//installChildren/object/installChildren/object[@class='InstallDirCont']/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <string>
            <xsl:for-each select="../rules[@logicalOperation='OR']/object">
                <xsl:value-of select="./property/string" />
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt; count(../object)"><xsl:value-of select="' || '" /></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

And I am running this XSLT in my PHP file (shown below) which is processing this xml/xslt files:

```
<?php
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('ELS92.iap_xml');

$xsldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xsldoc->load('transform.xslt');

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($xsldoc);

$result = $xslt->transformToDoc($xmldoc);
$result->save($xmldoc);
?>
```

Now when I run my php file like "php test.php" in CMD, I see the xml file updated but like this for instance:

```
  <property><string><![CDATA[CIAV100 || CIAV503]]></string></property>
```

instead of

```
<property name="Expression">
              <string><![CDATA[CIAV100 || CIAV503]]></string>
           </property>
```

Monday 11/11/2013: Query updated:

@Tim C : I made few shortcuts to avoid lengthy names used by InstallAnywhere software.
So now my original name for object class 'InstallBundle' is 'com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallBundle' and for 'InstallComponent' it is "com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallComponent". So in your xslt I made slight modifications to the template like this :

```
<xsl:template match="object[starts-with(@class, 'com.zerog.ia.installer.Install')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
```

I also added a new template matching for 'InstallDirCont' object class which is originally named as 'com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.InstallDirCont':

```
<xsl:template match="object[starts-with(@class, 'com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.InstallDirCont')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
```

all this works fine for me. Thanks a ton!

But now when I am dealing with a realtime InstallAnywhere generated file I am finding few warnings and errors in my PHP code.
Do you mind if I send you  the project file and may be you can look into more and find some exception handling functions for the xml file?

Query updated :15/11/2013:

@Tim C : Hi Tim, Sorry but I need further help. AFter running this XSLT through new project file (xml), my original xml file is going blank! May be some of the template rules are not matching and its failing to process further. But not sure. Let me clarify you that my xml file contains many InstallBundle object class under which there are multiple InstallCOmponent & InstallDirCOnt sub object classes. Now I find that in one of InstallBundle object class where its

```
 `<property name="bundleName">
<string><![CDATA[*** ** Database **]]</string>
</property>`
```

, it has a Installcomponent with

```
`<property name="componentName">
<string><![CDATA[Common]]></string>
</property>`
```

which has an improper structure below and moreover has no ruleId values and hence we dont need to copy its ruleId value into ruleExpression field. Could you please update the xslt code to bypass this condition and follow the process for other installComponents under this 'Database' contained in InstallBundle? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably start off by writing a template matching the **property** element you wish to change:

```
<xsl:template match="object[starts-with(@class, 'Install')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
```

But what you must do at this point, and what you haven't done in your example, is not only copy the existing element, but its attributes too

```
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <!-- Code to get rules -->
</xsl:copy>
```

To get the actual "rules" element, it looks like you just want to get the first following sibling in this case.

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::rules[1]" mode="copy" />
```

The `mode="copy"` is here because if you had a normal template matching **rules** it would subsequently break the copy of the actual **rules** element later on.

Within this special template matching "rules" you could create a variable to determine what operation is being used "AND" or "OR"

```
<xsl:template match="rules" mode="copy">
    <xsl:variable name="operator">
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@logicalOperation='OR'"> || </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise> &amp;&amp; </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

This means you avoid any code repetition and all rules can use the same template.

Then, it is just a case of writing out all the required propertie for the rule.

```
<xsl:for-each select="object/property[@name='ruleId']/string">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:value-of select="$operator" /></xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="string" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object[starts-with(@class, 'Install')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <string>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::rules[1]" mode="copy" />
         </string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rules" mode="copy">
    <xsl:variable name="operator">
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@logicalOperation='OR'"> || </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise> &amp;&amp; </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="object/property[@name='ruleId']/string">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:value-of select="$operator" /></xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As an aside, your XSLT is not well formed. Any instance of `&` needs to be escaped as `&amp;`. Further more you have the **xsl:output** statement occurring before the **xsl:transform** element, which contains the namespace declaration.

Comment: It's probably best to ask a whole new question, in this case, otherwise the question becomes quite cumbersome and hard to follow if it is changed to have new requirements. It's perfectly fine to ask a new question, and indeed you are more likely to get an answer that way (after all, other people will be able to answer it, not just me). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim, Your solution has worked like wonders to me. But could you please take sometime off and explain me the XSLT code that you have suggested here. I mean how it is meant to work! Thanks in Advance.